# Wifi network interface disappeared in iwconfig and ifconfig (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

When my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 turns on or reboots it doesn't connect to wifi because **wlp1s0** interface that was responsible for wifi adapter disappeared in `iwconfig` and `ifconfig`. However, when i turn off and on a laptop from the button (not from software), it connects to the wifi as usual, also `iwconfig` shows interface wlp1s0. But, after some time internet fades away even if it is connected to the properly working network and laptop doesn't show available wifi networks.

I tried ifconfig wlp1s0 up, but it can't see this interface

aircrack-ng may be the case of this problem, but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Anything in dmesg?

Comment: Prints a lot of 2, 3rd lines
[   14.000262] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   26.020652] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[   26.020694] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[   32.037210] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[   32.037246] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[   34.286223] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers

Comment: Is this still occurs ? if not how did you solve it, my friend has exact same issue.